# GSON Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 14 path $.dCharg

Tags: java, json, gson

I have **json structure** like this:

```
 {
  "dCharg": {
    "TEXT": 1000
  },
  "dICharg": {
    "TEXT": 1000
  },
  "dMaktx": {
    "TEXT": "No Material description available"
  },
  "dStatus": {
    "TEXT": "Batch is restricted"
  },
  "dStock": {
    "TEXT": "NULL"
  }
}
```

> Java code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.Data;


public class XJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{  \"dCharg\":{\"TEXT\":1000},\"dICharg\":{\"TEXT\":1000},\"dMaktx\":{\"TEXT\":\"No Material description avaibalbe\"},\"dStatus\":{\"TEXT\":\"Batch is restricted\"},\"dStock\":{\"TEXT\":\"NULL\"}}";       
        Data data = (Data) new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);

    }
}
```

> Data.java:

```
package com;

public class Data {
    private String dCharg;
    private String dICharg;
    private String dMaktx;
    private String dStatus;
    private String dStock;

    public String getDCharg() {
        return this.dCharg;
    }

    public void setDCharg(String dCharg) {
        this.dCharg = dCharg;
    }

    public String getDICharg() {
        return this.dICharg;
    }

    public void setDICharg(String dICharg) {
        this.dICharg = dICharg;
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I got this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was
 BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 14 path $.dCharg
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `String dCharg;`. What do you expect GSON to do with `{
    "TEXT": 1000
  }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because "dCharg": {
    "TEXT": 1000
  } is JsonObject and your trying to parse it into a String. There are two solutions to this:
1. Either you change the Json structure as per your Java Class Data. Like this:

```
 {
   "dCharg": 1000,
   "dICharg": 1000,
   "dMaktx": "No Material description available",
   "dStatus": "Batch is restricted",
   "dStock": "NULL"
 }
```

2. Or you change the Java Object with more nested objects to reflect your Json structure. Like this:

```
package com;

public class Data {
  private SubData dCharg;
  private SubData dICharg;
  private SubData dMaktx;
  private SubData dStatus;
  private SubData dStock;

  public SubData getDCharg() {
    return this.dCharg;
  }

  public void setDCharg(SubData dCharg) {
    this.dCharg = dCharg;
  }

  public SubData getDICharg() {
    return this.dICharg;
  } 

  public void setDICharg(SubData dICharg) {
    this.dICharg = dICharg;
  }
}

public class SubData {
   private String TEXT;
   public String getTEXT() {
    return this.TEXT;
   }

   public void setTEXT(String TEXT) {
    this.TEXT = TEXT;
   }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON says that dCharg is an object, not a String:

```
"dCharg":{"TEXT":1000}
```

If it was supposed to be a String, it would have looked like:

```
"dCharg":"1000"
```

So either the JSON is wrong, or your definition of the Data object is wrong.

**How you solve this problem depends on what you have control over.**

If you have control over the code that generates the JSON, then fix it appropriately.

If you only have control over the Data object, then you are going to have to change all the `String` variables to another object that matches the definition in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Gson expects a `String` but finds an object instead. Look closely at your json. You have

```
"dCharg" : {
    " TEXT" : 1000
 },
...
```

Where `{ "TEXT" : 1000 }` is a Json object (not a string).

Your java class on the other hand defines the field as a `String`.

Change your json to match your java object or vice versa. For example

```
{
    "dCharg" : "1000",
    ....
}
```